# C# call to WNetEnumResource stopped working in Windows 10.0.10586 and newer

Tags: c#, smb

C# call to WNetEnumResource stopped working in Windows 10.0.10586 and newer.
I see that this is due to SMB V1 is disabled. This causes computer broswer service to not run.

And we dont want to enable SMB v1 any more for many reasons.

How to come out of this problem?

we need an alternative if WNetEnumResource no more working as we need to gather all the domains and Shares and printer information.

What is the alternative to computer browser service

Your inputs are highly appreciated

Comment: You may want to use WMI. You can not get them in one WMI query but you can have multiple WMI queries to achieve what you want.

Comment: do you think will it be use for gathering all the domains and servers as well?

Comment: There is an [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17091/Build-Simple-Network-Browser) for that.